# ImageResizer and filenames containing "images"

Tags: c#, iis-7, imageresizer

I'm not sure if this is because ImageResizer saves images into the "images" folder but any requested image that goes through ImageResizer throws an "Access Denied" exception in the EventLog if the image filename contains the word "images".

Aside from not having this in the filename, is there any way around this?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using 3.3.3 or [3.4.0](http://imageresizing.net/releases/3-4-0)+? Did you customize the diskcache folder to /images/ instead of /imagecache/?

Comment: Please include the diagnostics page requested [on the ImageResizer support page](http://imageresizing.net/support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the disckcache folder was customised to /images/ instead of /imagecache/

This issue was fixed by upgrading to ImageResizer 3.4.1 (from 3.3 or 3.4) and the updated DiskCache plugin that comes with that